# Do on-demand resources get uploaded every time you submit out of Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I know it's a basic question but I haven't seen this mentioned anywhere. We upload new TestFlight builds on a daily basis. We're thinking of moving a lot of our embedded images to on-demand, but if each Xcode upload is going to include 1GB (or whatever) of resources, that's gonna get annoying, esp for team members with slow upload speeds.

Does the upload happen each time? Or are they versioned somehow so only re-upload when changed?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/IntrotoHostingODR.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH17-SW1

The document showing you can host on-demand resources for your app on any compliant web server.

Apps distributed through the App Store can retrieve on-demand resources from your own web server during development and testing, but must use Apple's hosting when published on the App Store.

Enterprise apps using in-house distribution can retrieve on-demand resources from your own web server during both development and distribution.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that hosting resources on your own server was only for testing on debug builds. Are you saying that resources from your own server can be used on App Store release builds, and that this is the only way to avoid uploading resources each time?